# Linkedin profile ids for site and API doesn't match

Tags: web-services, api, linkedin-api

I have problems while using linkedin api - member_id from site (from http://www.linkedin.com/sales/profile/{member_id}) doesn't work with Linkedin api. And whenever I try to:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id={member_id}
```

I get:

```
Invalid member id {mebmer_id}
```

So, what profiles data from public search api (https://www.linkedin.com/sales/search/results/people?=).

I can use to access to profile details with main Linkedin API?

Answer (score 0):

This is by design, to prevent abuse.  You must use the ID's you receive from other API calls to do member lookups with.